# TinyMCE text area value not render with form collection

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, tinymce

For my asp.net mvc 5 application I have use TinyMCE text editor. I my application I am passing front end value using formcollection.serialize method. Unfortunately the content of the textarea can't render by formcollection.serialize method. Here is my code below. It will be a great pleasure for me if anyone can help. With Thanks :

```js
tinyMCE.init({
            selector: "textarea"           
                
        });


//========Email Button
        
        $("#btnEmail").click(function () {
               tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);
        $.ajax({
                    
                    url: '@Url.Action("Email")',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $('#emailform').serialize(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true
            });
        });
```

```html
<textarea name="emailContent" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trying at last I have solved the issue perfectly. There were two things absent from my code: 1. form submission before ajax call and 2. adding an attribute [Validateinput(false)] just above my controller. Here is the final solution below:

```
 // Controller
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Email(FormCollection data)
{
    foreach (var key in data.AllKeys)
    {
        var value = data[key];
    }
   string Content = data["emailContent"];
}

Javascript:
tinyMCE.init({
selector: "textarea"        

});

//========Email Button
$("#btnEmail").click(function () {
tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);
    $('#emailform').submit();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Email")',
        type: "POST",

        data: $("#emailform").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true

    });
});

//========= HTML
<textarea name="emailContent" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```